# C++ 2d array row swap

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

Don't know if it matter but for the problem I use rand() to fill a 2d array with elements and CodeBloks for IDE.

I've been learning C++ and have gotten to pointers and 2d arrays and I've encountered something I don't understand why it works like this.

I had a tasks to swap two rows of a 2d array using pointers and this is how I swap the rows:

```
int *temp=arr[0];
 arr[0]=arr[1];
 arr[1]=temp;
```

And when my array is defined like this the code can compile without problem:

```
int a=5;
int b=3;
int **arr=new int*[a];
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        *(arr+i)=new int[b];
        for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
            *(*(arr+i)+j)=rand()%(125-15+1)+15;
            cout<<*(*(arr+i)+j)<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

But when its defined like this the code doesn't compile doesn't and I don't understand what is the difrence:

```
int a=5;
int b=3;
int arr[a][b];
```

And I get this as an error message:
invalid array assignment|
incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [b]'|

Aren't the two definitions equvelent trought the compiler or does something else happen?

Comment: Sizes of arrays must be compile time constant.

Comment: A multidimensional array is *not* the same as an array of pointers

Comment: In the first example, a 2D array is not an array of pointers, so two rows can't be swapped by simply swapping pointers.   It is an array of arrays.   To swap two arrays (including two rows of a 2D array, which are each an array) it is necessary to swap their elements one by one.      Also (not directly related to the question, but something you also need to learn) `int arr[a][b]` where `a` and `b` are variables is not valid in standard C++ (it is a *non-standard* extension supported by some compilers but not others).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.

With

```
int **arr=new int*[a];
```

`arr` is not a two-dimensional array but a pointer to the first element in an array of pointers, and your code is only swapping pointers.

But you can't assign between arrays;

```
int a[3] {1,2,3};
int b[3] {4,5,6};
a = b; // Error
```

or from a pointer to an array;

```
int x = 0;
int a[3] {1,2,3};
a = &x; // Error
```

However, an array can be implicitly converted into a pointer to its first element, and when you use arrays your "swapping code" is equivalent to

```
int *temp = &arr[0][0]; // Pointer to the first element of the array arr[0]
arr[0] = &arr[1][0]; // Try to assign a pointer to the first element of arr[1] to the array arr[0]
arr[1] = temp; // Try to assign a pointer to the array arr[1]
```

In summary, you can't swap arrays, you need to do the swapping element-wise.

Or use `std::array` instead of "native" arrays, or `std::vector` if you need to determine the dimensions at runtime.